# SystemVerilog: String to Circuit Net

Tags: environment-variables, simulation, system-verilog, test-bench

Assuming that I set one environment variable before launching a logic simulation of my circuit wrapped in a testbench written in SystemVerilog, I want to check whether it is possible to read the variable and try to map it to a net of the circuit.

For instance:

```
#### from the bash script that invokes the logic simulator ####
export NET_A=tb_top.module_a.submodule_b.n1
```

```
//// inside the tb_top in system verilog ////

import "DPI-C" function string getenv(input string env_name);

always_ff @(posedge clk, nenedge rst_n) begin

    if (getenv("NET_A") == 1'b1) begin

        $display("Hello! %s has the value 1", getenv("NET_A"));
    end 
end
```

In the example above I simply want to check whether the current net i.e., `NET_A`is assigned at a certain point in the simulation the logic value of 1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: nets are initialized to 'z', so if it has a different value, it is driven. Exception is a case when it is driven by 'z'.  There are also vpi(Local)Driver/load features which you might be able to use. To access a net by string name, you need to employ VPI interface (called from your import/context function or from a vpi system function). You will need to know a full hierarchical name of your net (the instance path).

Comment: @Serge The hierarchy is known up until the nesting unit i.e.e, the unit that engulfs the nets that I wish to probe. I am unaware of the VPI interface. Mind elaborating a little bit on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemVerilog has a C-based API (Verilog Procedural Interface VPI) that gives you access to a simulator's database. There are routines like `vpi_get_handle_by_name` which gives you a handle to an signal looked up by  a string name. And then you can use `vpi_get_value` the gives you the current value of that signal.

Use of the VPI needs quite a bit of additional knowledge and many simulators give you built-in routines to handle this common application without having to break into C code. In Modelsim/Questa, it is called *Signal_Spy*.

But regardless of whether you use the VPI or tool specific routines, looking up a signal by string name has severe performance implications because it prevents many optimizations. Unless a signal represents a storage element, it usually does not keep its value around for queries.

It would be much better to use the signal path name directly

```
vlog ... +define+NET_A=tb_top.module_a.submodule_b.n1
```

Then in your code

```
if (`NET_A == 1'b1) begin
```